# How to make a delay inside cron on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I am using node js with the node-cron library. I need to make a delay in executing the code inside the cron. I tried await and setInterval, but the second cron function is not executed. What can be done?

```js
cron.schedule("*/10 * * * * *", async function() {
  FakeGames.StartGame();
  await wait(3000);
  FakeGames.StopGame()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use settimeout, like this, so your `FakeGames.stopGame()` will execute after a certain dealy

```js
    cron.schedule("*/10 * * * * *", function () {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         FakeGames.StartGame();
         setTimeout(() => {
           FakeGames.StopGame();
         resolve();
       }, delayInMilliSeconds);
     });
   });
```